# How can I get the individual RAM usage of running apps?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I'm working on a project for Blackberry devices and I have to show the individual RAM usage for all running apps. Is there any way to do that using the Blackberry Java Development Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no API available to get such information.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately only common stats are available. Take a look at [MemoryStats](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/MemoryStats.html) and [Memory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Memory.html) classes.

Comment: I'm already able to do that. I was wanting to get individual memory stats, if possible.